# Unpredictable effect of the use of DateTimeZone PHP class?

Tags: php, timezone, datetime-format

I am trying to fetch date/timestamp data from the database and convert them into JSON/ISO8601 datetime strings with the timezone added, this is continuation of the [What determines (how to configure) what format string is used by php PDO driver for values of date and timestamp fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483136/what-determines-how-to-configure-what-format-string-is-used-by-php-pdo-driver)

I have the following test code:

```
        $t1 = '2019-10-10 00:00:00';
        $t2 = '1899-12-30 06:10:38'; 
        $t3 = '2019-12-30 06:10:38';
        $t4 = '2019-10-10 00:00:01';
        $dt1 = \DateTime::createFromFormat ('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t1, new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Tallinn'));
        $dt2 = \DateTime::createFromFormat ('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t2, new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Tallinn'));
        $dt3 = \DateTime::createFromFormat ('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t3, new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Tallinn'));
        $dt4 = \DateTime::createFromFormat ('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t4, new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Tallinn'));
        return $dt1->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO')."\r\n".$dt2->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO')."\r\n".$dt3->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO')."\r\n".$dt4->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO');
```

But result is completely unpredictable:

```
2019-10-10T00:00:00+0300
1899-12-30T06:10:38+0139
2019-12-30T06:10:38+0200
2019-10-10T00:00:01+0300
```

I provide the exact time zone (Europe/Tallinn) for each of the 4 datetime strings, but the actual timezone for the DateTime instances is different. I expect 03 or 02 in each case (I am not sure about the use of daylight saving effect), but I clearly can not expect 0139. What is happening here?

PHP 7.x.

Comment: Just a guess but wouldn't Tallinn have been part of Russia in 1899 and have used the old Julian calendar which was a couple of weeks different from the Gregorian calendar?

Comment: `+01:39` is simply the [Local Mean Time (LMT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_mean_time) entry.  That's normal for early pre-known-time-zone dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those timezones are all correct, the +3 is applied on summer time (from 28th of March until 31th of October), and +2 is the normal time. About the 1899 timezone is also correct as you can verify [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/estonia/tallinn)

[image: 1899 Timezone]