# Why is dbTimeStamp() adding a comma?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, adodb-php

I have the following code:

```
$NOW = $db->dbTimeStamp(time());
```

And using that in a query it is producing a timestamp like this:

```
2021-01-13, 08:17:06PM
```

However, that comma seems to be causing the query to fail in SQL Server 2005.  Is there a way to get it to not include that comma.

I'm running PHP 7.4 on Debian 10 connecting to SQL Server 2005 with the odbc driver.

EDIT: Here's how I'm using it in a query:

```
$sql = "UPDATE podocument SET deleted = '1', lastseen = {$NOW} WHERE (purchaseOrderId = '{$purchaseOrderId}')";
$res = $db->execute($sql);
```

Comment: Wow, SQL 2005.  You know that has been end of life for over 5 years and probably vulnerable to dozens of exploits by now.   As far as using that value in a SQL query, can you not just rewrite the query to use the GETDATE() T-SQL function as you seem to be just getting the current date and time anyway?

Comment: Exactly HOW does one use that in a query? Show your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483136/what-determines-how-to-configure-what-format-string-is-used-by-php-pdo-driver

Comment: @MartinCairney This is a legacy system that I've taken over and I'm working on getting it upgraded.  But, the reason I can't use `GETDATE()` is because sometimes I need to replace `time()` with a date/time string that I've received externally.

Comment: @MitchWheat I'm not using Yii or PDO so I'm not sure what that has to do with this question?

Comment: Can you show how you are passing it back to the SQL query? Since that part is likely where the error is arising it would help to see your implementation.

Comment: @MartinCairney Check the EDIT in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Darrell

Rather than using the time() function, can you instead use the date() function as described [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and using a format string of `"Ymd H:i:s"`

Using this format string is always correctly recognised in SQL Server.